# java Get value from xml tag

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an XML file:

```
<Header>
 <Id>A203</Id>
 <Name>ABC</Name>
</Header>
```

I'm trying to check whether the XML file's `Id` value is "A203" or not. I tried the following way but still can't get the value. I can't use xPath because I have an older Java version.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbfaFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = dbfaFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(xmlfile);

doc.getElementsByTagName("Id").item(0).getNodeValue());   --tried this but cant
```

Comment: can you use external libraries? what if you have multiple headers in the xml? are you looking for a general or localized solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the node value of an element will return `null` (as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html)).

Instead you need to either get the element's text content (since Java 5):

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("Id").item(0).getTextContent();
```

Or, if you're stuck in Java 1.4 or older, you can access the element's text node and get the text node's value:

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("Id").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

Comment: getTextContent(); i cant use this method, is it require newer version of jdk?

Comment: Wow. You're still using Java 1.4? Or even older? Anyway, the second option should work, or you can implement your own `getTextContent()`. See for example [here](http://nofoe.blogspot.jp/2008/06/java-14-get-node-text.html).